# Which is the right approach to validate a mandatory field in front end or back end?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, restful-authentication

I am new in back end development. I have already write the API to update user info, whose request body like this -

```
{
   "id": 26,
   "email": "tom.richards@yahoo.com",
   "firstName": "Tommy",
   "lastName": "Richards",
   "photoUrl": null,
   "userAddress": [
        {
           "id": 8,
           "type": "home",
           "addressLine1": "DP Road",
           "addressLine2": "Main Street",
           "city": "Los Angel",
           "state": "CA",
           "country": "USA",
           "postalCode":915890
        },
        {
          "id": 25,
          "type": "office",
          "addressLine1": "Dr Red Road",
          "addressLine2": null,
          "city": "SA",
          "state": "CA",
          "country": "USA",
          "postalCode":918950
       }
    ]
}
```

Where should ideally validate the address type [in my case home or office] in front end[Web site or Phone]  or back end [server side] or both side? Which is good approach to validate address type ? If we validate it on backend side, which will cause any performance issue ?

Note -
If the developer pass any string, the address type of like pass string will create in DB.

Comment: ALWAYS sanitize and validate user-inputted data on the server.  Any front-end validation is purely to enhance user experience. Most websites you enjoy using validate data on the front and then again after it reaches the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reasons**
Front End Validation : Validation on the server, User has to wait for the response in case of the invalid data.

Backend Validation : To make sure that the data could not alter by the intruder.

Validate @database end : Like Mongoose provide the built in and custom validation.

As per the requirement we have to cross check the data before user profile update.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good approach for the back end validate everything it gets from any web request, as you can't tell if its a good request coming from your web site or some other source (maybe even some malicious attack). The back-end must protect itself and validates everything it gets.

On top of it, on some (if not all) cases it's good to do some validations on the front end side too, one reason is that if you have a request that you know the back end is going to fail- save yourself the trouble and check it before you do an expensive request

Comment: If we validate address-type at back end side, which will cause any performance issue  or will taking more time for response ?

Comment: It will, but this can be a very fast validation. On the other hand, not validating and getting a failure to insert to db can be slower (not to mention the option of inserting bad unvalidated data into the db)

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I will definitely improve this. Is there any standard documentation or book available for how to design a powerful and good API and backend as well ? If any please guide. 
Once again thank you for your valuable suggestion.